# A problem with Epsilon-Delta Continuity regarding a multivariable function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, continuity

I have the following function for which I am attempting to utilize the $\epsilon - \delta$ definition to determine if the function is continuous

$$  f(x) = \frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{x_0} \quad D_f = R \backslash \{0\}$$
and I have rearranged the function to the following 
$$ f(x) = \frac{x_0}{x_0x} - \frac{x_0}{x_0x} = \frac{x_0-x}{x_0x} \\$$

However I am unsure of how to continue working with the following definition:

$$ | x - x_0 | \leq \delta \Rightarrow |{f(x) - f(x_0)}| \leq \epsilon $$ 
as it seems that the top of the function will simply result in 0 or is my algebra simply much worse than I thought? For example :

$$ \lvert f(x) - f(x_0) \rvert = \lvert \frac{x_0-x}{x_0x} - \frac{x_0-x}{x_0x} \rvert = \lvert \frac{x_0-x - x_0 + x}{x_0x}\rvert $$

Comment: It isn't equal to $0$ : $$f(x_0) \neq \frac{x_0 - x}{x_0x}$$ it should actually be$$  f(x_0) = \frac{x_0-x_0}{x_0^2} = 0$$ which means $$ \vert f(x) - f(x_0) \vert = \vert f(x) \vert  $$

Comment: Yep. I'm dumb for not seeing that. Thanks